# Async Call to DB in WPF Application

Tags: wpf, database, asynchronous

I have a stored procedure which runs for 8 mins, need to trigger the SP which will update records in multiple tables from WPF application, but thats timing out as the SP runs for 8 minutes, So planning to implement Asynchronous call to the SP like, just triggering the SP to run, which eventually when completed updates the records in 8 minutes. I know that SP can be optimized, but just want to know if at all there is a feature to trigger and dont wait for the result.

Thanks in Advance ..

Answer (score 1):

Its best to perform the long-running work (e.g. communication with server/DB) on the background thread and once the thread completes, have the UI thread update the UI.

With BackgroundWorker:

Easy to implement background threading.

```
var worker = new BackgroundWorker();

worker.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
{
    // long running work
};

worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) =>
{
    // Update UI
};

worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

async/await pattern:

The action following the the await keyword, which returns a Task, will be run on a background thread and the rest of the method will act as a callback.

```
public async void DoWork()
{
    // Do long running task
    var data = await Task.Run(() => new object());

    // Update UI here
}
```

TaskFactory:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new Object()).ContinueWith(task => MessageBox.Show(task.Result.ToString()), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```